# opengl draw surface volume from data set

Tags: opengl

The code is loading a bin file which contains (x,y,z) coordinates for a set of points.
Let say the points form a cube and that there are some points in the cube as well, how do i make the cube look like a surface cube instead of a set of points?

I read about marching cubes and barycentric coordinates, but i don't understand how to do that in C++ and opengl. Thanks.

Comment: If you're interested in stuff like this in general, you might want to have a look at MeshLab and its code, as well as the accompanying blog http://meshlabstuff.blogspot.com/

Comment: i'll check meshlabstuff, it looks really cool. I'll also try to find some papers on point cloud triangulation methods. If you guys have some papers i could read, let me know. Thanks for the quick answers!

Comment: something cool would be to find a tutorial on how to transfer the point cloud bunny to the mesh bunny in opengl.

Answer (score 0):

If they form an axis-aligned cube all you need to do is draw a cube from `min(x), min(y), min(z)` to `max(x), max(y), max(z)` where `min(x)` represents the minimum of all `x` coordinates.

Comment: They doesn't necessarily form a cube, they could take any shape. I'm trying to do it with a cube because it makes thing simplier.